# How to get the last 4 months records from the table using sql

Tags: sql

I wish to get last 4 months records from customer table using sql query.

My database structure.

[image]

I have tried like below, but not work

```
select * from Customers where month(date) = 3
```

Comment: could you please provide sample data and expected output - to get proper answer it is necessary to post question with more details

Comment: Hi, @Sri. With this type of question, we cannot help you. I am voting to close this question. You would need to provide us with example data, your schema, which database you are working with, and any attempts you have made towards achieving your goals. You should consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You want to do this in excel, right?

Comment: Nope, I want it in sql

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which DBMS you used, the answer may vary.

But roughly, this would help:

```
select * from Customers where dateCol >= ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate), -4); --oracle
select * from Customers where dateCol >= now()-interval 4 month; --mysql
SELECT * from Customers WHERE dateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I get the last 4 month details, but if i need to get records from september 21st to till date how do i modify the above query

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using RDBMS